# Need Help adding Magento2 Patch to IDE

Tags: magento2, patches

Getting an error when changing Theme via admin Dash... "Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Area is already set" Found the solution patch from Magento. but I don't know where to import the file to my IDE.

Please find attached screen shot[image: Error while changing Theme] along with problem being resolved[VIa Github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14968)... I have the Patch to import to IDE... I just don't know where it goes... 
Also This is the Patch from Magento 2: [Patch - MAGETWO-93036](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download)

Can anyone help Please? Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Should read this article: https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005484154-Create-a-patch-for-a-Magento-2-Composer-installation-from-a-GitHub-commit

Comment: Hey @KhoaTruongDinh, Thank you for getting back to me, I tried your Link... Followed instructions and nothing happened, Am i missing something? Thank you,